# ASP.NET passing along Windows Authentication credentials

Tags: asp.net, windows-authentication, delegation

I've got an ASP.NET web application which uses Windows Authentication. This application needs to connect to another ASP.NET web service (which also uses Windows Authentication) and use the same credentials that it received from the user's browser. Can this be done and how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't believe you can do this without Kerberos Authentication.  You can't delegate credentials to another system.

I think [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/dotnetremoting/archive/2006/07/06/662599.aspx) will start to set you on the right track.

Comment: In fact, Kerberos is EXACTLY what I'm interested in. And, the real question that I have is much broader than this, but I hope that the answer to this one will set me on the right path.

Comment: Aha... I read the link in the link you gave that explained how Kerberos works (conceptually). That explains why the touch on the DC is required, and why it's not really what I wanted in the first place. Thanks!